# How do I assume correct values for x in absolute value function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Given,
$|\frac{1}{x}-2|<4$, I can solve this via the theorem approach $|x-a|<b\Rightarrow-b<x-a<b$..... but in the above question, there comes a possibility in $-4<\frac{1}{x}-2$ where the solution for it is less than $-\frac{1}{2}$ but it can change if I assume $\frac{1}{x}$ to be a negative value. How do I decide in these question of structure $x-a$ about value of $x$?

Comment: I cant see other part of my question so im posting it here

Comment: solve this via the theorem approach |x-a|<b= 
-b<x-a<b..... but in the above question,there comes a possibility in -4<1/x-2 where the solution for it is less than -1/2 but it can change if i assume 1/x to be a negative value. How do i decide in these question of structure x-a about value of x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $x \neq 0$.  You can avoid casework by squaring both sides, then solving the resulting quadratic. 
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{x} - 2\right| & < 4\\
\left|\frac{1 - 2x}{x}\right| & < 4\\
\left(\frac{1 - 2x}{x}\right)^2 & < 16\\
\frac{1 - 4x + 4x^2}{x^2} & < 16\\
1 - 4x + 4x^2 & < 16x^2\\
0 & < 12x^2 + 4x - 1\\
0 & < (6x - 1)(2x + 1)
\end{align*}
The inequality is true when both factors have the same sign.  Both factors are positive if $x > 1/6$.  Both factors are negative if $x < -1/2$.  Hence, the solution set is 
$$\left(-\infty, -\frac{1}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{1}{6}, \infty\right)$$

Comment: Nice solution +1

Answer (score 0):

You have $-2<{1\over x} <6$ thus:

If $x>0$ we have $-2x<1<6x$ so $x>1/6$.

If $x<0$ we have $-2x>1>6x$ so $x<-1/2$.

So $x\in (-\infty, -{1\over 2})\cup ({1\over 6},\infty)$.

Comment: if you do it x-a way alone, how can i explain -2<1/x is x<1/-2?I would have to make some assumptions i think

Comment: Which line is that?